# Cordova: Real hardware resolution

Tags: javascript, android, apache, cordova

Using Apache Cordova I cannot get the real device resolution to work with. I would like to have my app/game running full screen, and to have full 1920 x 1080 pixels to work with on my HTC One m7. I check my resolution with:

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

...and I am getting 640 x 480 instead of Full HD. I tried to work with <viewport ...> but with no luck. In other words: is there any way to get the device resolution 1:1 with Cordova app?

Comment: @PeterS Not really, that one is native, this one is hybrid question

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (not 100% sure though) you get 1:1, what Cordova returns to you are dp (or dip - density independent pixels) and not px (CSS logic pixels). You can try using window.devicePixelRatio to get the conversion ratio to get logic pixels. ie. try something like this:

```
var realWidth = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio
var realHeight = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio
```

Also if you have this in your meta (header) target-densitydpi=device-dpi, try removing it.